# Creating a flat illustrator effect which makes it look like 3D (illustrator effect)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Back with another question.
Does anyone knows how to create a object like the one underneath. 
It looks like it's 3d but it's a flat effect.

Image credits: Take Chabukiani

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? The 3d effect is merely by the distance between the lines that makes it look raised / lowered, these lines are hand drawn, there's no filter / effect for that. Can you expand your question to make more clear where are you having trouble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one method

1. Create two open paths as shown, drawn with the Pen Tool.
2. Create a 10 step blend
3. Create an origin marked with guides, rotate and copy the blend 90° around that origin.

[image]

Comment: It's weird how often I see closed questions with great answers like this. Nice job Billy Kerr.